# Pipeline idea not working due to pointers (C)

Tags: c, pointers, redirect, parent-child, pipeline

I was working on a little program I had to make some time ago, and I wanted to short it up.

This little program was about one thread creating several child who would redirect their standard output/input one to another with pipes in order, except for the last child, who won't redirect it's standard output, like this.

```
Parent pipe  child1   pipe   child2  pipe   last child
       __             __             __
O-----|__|-----O-----|__|-----O-----|__|-----O -> Stdout
```

First time I face this code, I made a matrix with a dimension of [n_child][2], and made a pipe from every position of that matrix, so it was very easy to connect every pipe to every child when needed. But now I want to try it only with 2 pipes, and "playing" with inheritance.

Maybe I'm not explaining myself really well, so I think everything would be better understood with my code,so here we go.

```c
piping_function(int number_of_child){

    int i;
    int olddesc[2];
    int newdesc[2]; //Here I create the descriptors of the pipes I'll use
    int *olddir;
    int *newdir;
    if(pipe(olddesc)<0 || pipe(newdesc) < 0){  //I create the pipes
        //Error 
    }
    olddir = olddesc;
    newdir = newdesc; //And attach the directions to the array's direction (we will see later why)
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_child; i++){
        chaddr[i] = fork();
        switch(chaddr[i]){
            case -1:
                //Error trace
            case 0:
                dup2(olddesc[0],0); //Here I redirect the pipe who connect the previous child's pipe to the standard input
                if(i != number_of_child - 1)
                    dup2(newdesc[1],1); //And here, except from the last child, I redirect the standard output to the pipe who will connect to the standard input of the next child
                close(olddesc[0]);
                close(newdesc[1]); //I close the descriptors I don't need
                //Several child operations with standard input-output (end up returning 0/1 after the pipeline is connected, so no child will create any child)
            default:
                if(i == 0)
                    dup2(olddesc[1], 1); //I want the standard output of the principal proccess only on the first pipe
                olddir = newdir; //Here I would want the direction of the "old" pipe to be the direction of the "new" pipe, in order to achieve the pipeline
                if(pipe(newdesc)<0)
                    //Error
                break;
        }//End of switch
    }//End of for
    close(olddesc[0]);close(olddesc[1]);close(newdesc[0]);close(newdesc[1]); //I don't need these descriptors anymore, as they must be redirected to the standard's input/output of the process they need.
}//End of function
```

Well, there is my code. I think I can see the mistake I'm doing, when I make olddir be newdir, and create the pipe, I'm doing olddir to be also that new pipe right? So here comes my question:

Is there any way to achieve that change? I mean, the thing I want is to equal olddir (who is the address of olddesc, right? so if I change that address olddesc's address will be also changed, right?) to newdir, in order to continue with the pipe I created before to redirect the standard output of the "next" child, but I also want newdir to be a NEW pipe.

I don't really know if I explained myself right, I'm not a native speaker and it's a bit difficult to explain these kind of ideas in other language. Feel free to correct any grammar mistake, I'd appreciate it, and to ask any question about the code, as maybe I'm not giving the point I wanted to.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, first impressions: You need `break;` instructions in your `switch` as `case` falls through in C. You have a `fork` in a loop without exiting the loop in the child. This will give you (order of) `number_of_children*number_of_children` processes not just a line.

Comment: @user3710044 I commented the break thing. In my code every child ends on a execvp, and, in case it fails, returns an error, kills every child and makes an exit(1), so this is not the failure as every child ends exiting, making them impossible to go back to the for loop. I thought on a solution, but the sad thing is that it works on the paper but not in the computer haha. If I make it I'll post it, just in case somebody wonders if it can work (but it seems is not the case). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally made it, but changing the point of view and not working with any address overwrite, only playing with the iterations, in order always keep the record of one of the two pipes. I didn't really solve the address problem, but it works so, I'm satisfied.

```c
piping_function(int number_of_child){

    int i;
    int olddesc[2];
    int newdesc[2]; //Here I create the descriptors of the pipes I'll use

    //Now we'll start from the last pipe, so we can connect the parent to the first one and not connect the last child's output.
    for(i = number_of_child - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        //Instead of changing addresses, I'll play with the "i"
        if(i%2==0){
            close(newdesc[0]); //We close the last descriptors 
            close(newdesc[1]);
            pipe(newdesc); //And create a new pipe!
        }
        else{
            close(olddesc[0]);
            close(olddesc[1]);
            pipe(oldesc);
        }
        chaddr[i] = fork();
        switch(chaddr[i]){
            case -1:
                //Error trace
            case 0:
                if(i%2==0){
                    dup2(newdesc[0],0); //Here I redirect the pipe who connect the previous child's pipe to the standard input
                    if(i != number_of_child - 1)
                        dup2(olddesc[1],1); //And here, except from the last child, I redirect the standard output to the pipe who will connect to the standard input of the next child
                    close(newdesc[1]);
                    close(olddesc[0]); //I close the descriptors I don't need    
                }
                else{
                    dup2(olddesc[0],0); //Here I redirect the pipe who connect the previous child's pipe to the standard input
                    if(i != number_of_child - 1)
                        dup2(newdesc[1],1); //And here, except from the last child, I redirect the standard output to the pipe who will connect to the standard input of the next child
                    close(olddesc[1]);
                    close(newdesc[0]); //I close the descriptors I don't need
                }
                //Several child operations with standard input-output (end up exiting 0/1 after the pipeline is connected, so no child will create any child)
            default:
                if(i == 0)
                    dup2(newdesc[1], 1); //I want the standard output of the principal proccess only on the first pipe
                break;
        }//End of switch
    }//End of for
    close(olddesc[0]);close(olddesc[1]);close(newdesc[0]);close(newdesc[1]); //I don't need these descriptors anymore, as they must be redirected to the standard's input/output of the process they need.
}//End of function
```

*Edit:

I don't think it's good to close always the descriptors, even without creating anything, I saw I left them this way on this piece of code, but in order to make it work correctly we should only close the descriptors when created so an if would be needed on every close.